# How to do Fast deleting in C # ? and How to find which function taking too much time?

Tags: c#

I have added more than 70 entries then i tried to delete those entries but it will take too much time i.e more 5minutes , how to do fast deleting ? my codes below:

```
protected virtual void OnDeleteButtonClick()
{ if (RecipientsListBox != null)
        {
            DKSelectedIndexCollection list = RecipientsListBox.SelectedIndexes;
     if ((list != null) &&
         (mRecipientsBindingHelper != null) &&
         (mRecipientsBindingHelper.RecipientList != null))
     {
         // Remove the items from the binding list (do it in reverse to preserve the index)
         for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
         {
                              {
                 RecipientsBindingHelper.RecipientList.RemoveAt(list[i]);
             }

             EnableRecipientListPanelControls();

         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please, do some code formatting. Respect people who will read your question

Comment: i thought For loop only taking too much time ? is it correct ?

Comment: What are the two for loops for?

Comment: only one for loop only

Answer (score 3):

It's not really clear from your code what all the types you are using are.  However if you just want to remove everything from a list use Clear().

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a.aspx

That said, if you really are just removing 70 entries from a list with RemoveAt(), then clearly that won't add 5 minutes to the runtime vs using Clear(), so the times you are seeing are probably due to something else not evident from your explanation. Possibly related to your second inner loop?

Comment: Now i have shared correct code please find it .. sorry for the inconvenient

Comment: Ok thanks. I would still try using Clear() if you want to remove every item from the list. But it makes no sense that the above loop takes 5 minutes to execute if it's only looping 70 times.  So something else is going on within the code that is taking up that time, it's not the mechanics of the loop itself.

Comment: hi James now See the code and give your comment

Comment: You can use the DateTime millisecond timer to log out the time in milliseconds at various places in the code to help narrow down what is taking so long.  There isn't much that can be gained from just looking at the code here.

Comment: oh k james .. i have added 100 entry from that i am deleting 70 entries .. so clear() is correct way to use ?

Comment: No, clear will remove everything. so if you just want to remove some of the items you would have to use a loop of some sort. But just to repeat - the 5 minutes is not being taken up due to the choice of method of evicting 70 items from a list. Something else is taking the time. There is no way to know what that is without profiling the code. Looking at this code won't help with that.

Comment: k will try my best .. anyone can share your valuable comments here.. i am waiting eagerly to learn from you